# Generating in-order constrained sets

Tags: algorithm, set, abstract

First I will paste the scenario and then pose my question:

Suppose you have a list of Categories, for example:

`Food,Meat,Dairy,Fruit,Vegetable,Grain,Wheat,Barley`

Now you have a list of items that fits into one or more of the categories listed above.

Here is a sample list of items:
`Pudding,Cheese,Milk,Chicken,Barley,Bread,Couscous,Fish,Apple,Tomato,
 Banana,Grape,Lamb,Roast,Honey,Potato,Rice,Beans,Legume,Barley Soup`

As you see every item fits into at least one category, it could fit into more, or possibly all but the minimum is always one.

For example `Cheese` is a `Food` and `Dairy`.

Each item has two attributes:
1) A Price Tag
2) A Random Value

A set is defined as having every category mapped to an item.
In other words all categories must be present in a set.

A set from the items above could be:

`[Pudding,Lamb,Milk,Apple,Tomato,Legume,Bread,Barley Soup]`

As you see each item is mapped to a category slot:

- Pudding is mapped to Food Category
- Lamb is mapped to Meat Category
- Milk is mapped to Dairy Category
- Apple is mapped to Fruit Category
- Tomato is mapped to Vegetable Category
- Legume is mapped to Grain Category
- Bread is mapped to Wheat Category
- Barley Soup is mapped to Barley Category

My question is, what is the most efficient algorithm for generating in-order sets of the above categories from a list of items given.

The best set is defined as having the highest Random Value in total.

The only constraint is that any generated set cannot, in total, exceed a certain fixed amount, in other words, all generated sets should be within this Price Cap.

Hope I am clear, thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @SidS I have tried using a heap structure to keep the best set on top and I keep on generating next best combos and add it to the heap, and if the popped value is valid i.e it is under the price cap, I consider it a valid set.

Comment: Please provide an example of input and output.

Comment: If you're trying to brute force every possible combination, then a multi-base counting algorithm should work.

Comment: Note that your question has nothing to do with C++, I just removed that tag. In general, algorithms are independent from the programming language, though of course some may be more complicated to implement, depending on the language.

Comment: @user3386109 Duly noted, however I am trying to generate everything in order.

Comment: What do you mean by "in-order sets"? What order rules apply?

Comment: @TedHopp The best set is a set that has the highest total value, so in-order sets would mean that I want to generate, let's say the top x sets (in order). Everything is in my question.

Comment: One other question: does a set need to contain as many items as there are categories? Or can one item (e.g., `Cheese`) serve as a representative for multiple categories? Put another way, if `Cheese` is inserted as a representative of `Food`, can something else be used to represent `Dairy` (thereby increasing the value of the set)?

Comment: I think you should try implementing this using `Disjoint Sets`.

Comment: @TedHopp One item per category, where each item in a set represents every Category, and no duplicate items that can fit into two categories.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Please write a full answer that I can understand :)

Comment: "highest Random Value in total" refers to the sum of the Random Values in the set, correct?

Comment: @GeorgiGerganov yes.

Comment: It seems I got question wrongly, so I deleted my answer related to knapsack. Do you think there is any problem with your current approach? I think generating every possible set that's under given price tag with backtracking and sorting it or putting into heap is right approach here.

Comment: @miradham It does the job with 100 items or less but once above that it takes a long time. I don't believe there is no optimization here.

Comment: If you use backtracking with recursion its complexity would be `O(2^n)`. I tried to reproduce it and indeed it slows down for items more than 100. I could avoid this problem by checking top x values. Also I sorted input value based on order value, price and name. You can see my code [here](https://gist.github.com/mkamilov/a0341ed921167da438b3030468abaec3) Not really sure if my randomly generated test data matches with yours, but it works fine for items more than 1000 since I am getting only top x items where x resides within 100.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample inputs and corresponding outputs? It would things much clearer.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve is a form of maximal matching, and I don't know if there is an efficient way to compute in-order sets, but still this reduction might help you.

Define a bipartite graph with on one side one node per category, and on the other side one node per item. Add an edge between an item and a category if that items belongs in that category, with a weight defined by the random value of the item.

A "set" as you defined it is a maximum-cardinality matching in that graph.
They can be enumerated in reasonable time, as proved by Takeaki Uno in
"[A Fast Algorithm for Enumerating Non-Bipartite Maximal Matchings](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~uno/papers/enummat_nii.pdf)", and it is likely to be even faster in your situation because your graph is bipartite.

Among those sets, you are looking for the ones with maximal weight and under a price constraint. Depending on your data, it may be enough to just enumerate them all, filter them based on the price, and sort the remaining results if there are not too many.

If that is not the case, then you may find the best set by solving the combinatorial optimization problem whose objective function is the total weight, and whose constraints are the price limit and the cardinal (known as maximum-weighted matching in the litterature). There may even be solvers already online once you write the problem in this form. However, this will only provide one such set rather than a sorted list, but as this problem is very hard in the general case, this is the best you can hope for. You would need more assumptions on your data to have better results (like bounds on the maximum number of such sets, the maximum number of items that can belong to more than k categories, etc.)

Comment: I get the gist of what you present here, but it's not quite a full answer, as I am unsure of how to apply the combinatorial optimization problem here. My knowledge on graph algorithms are  peripheral so a complete solution would be necessary, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here is my second try to answer this question.

Lets say we have following input

```
class Item {
public:
    // using single unsigned int bitwise check sets
    unsigned int category;
    int name;
    int value;
    int price;
...
};

class ItemSet
{
public:
    set<Item> items;
    int sum;
};
```

First, sort input data based on highest random value, then lowest price

```
bool operator<(const Item& item1, const Item& item2) {
    if (item1.value == item2.value) {
        if (item1.price == item2.price) {
            return item1.name < item2.name;
        }
        return item1.price > item2.price;
    }
    return item1.value < item2.value;
}
...
vector<Item> v = generateTestItem();
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater<Item>());
```

Next use backtracking to collect top sets into heap until conditions met. Having sorted input data in our backtracking algorithm guarantees that collected data is top based on highest `value` and lowest `price`. One more thing to note, I compared item categories (`currentCats`) with bit manipulation which gives `O(1)` complexity.

```
priority_queue<ItemSet> output;
void helper(vector<Item>& input, set<Item>& currentItems, unsigned int currentCats, int sum, int index)
{
    if (index == input.size()) {
        // if index reached end of input, exit
        addOutput(currentItems);
        return;
    }
    if (output.size() >= TOP_X) {
        // if output data size reached required size, exit
        return;
    }
    if (sum + input[index].price < PRICE_TAG) {
        if ((input[index].category & currentCats) == 0) {
            // this category does not exists in currentCats
            currentItems.insert(input[index]);
            helper(input, currentItems, currentCats | input[index].category, sum + input[index].price, index + 1);
        }
    } else { 
        addOutput(currentItems);
        return;
    }
    if (currentItems.find(input[index]) != currentItems.end()) {
        currentItems.erase(input[index]);
    }
    helper(input, currentItems, currentCats, sum, index + 1);
    return;
}

void getTopItems(vector<Item>& items)
{
    set<Item> myset;
    helper(items, myset, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

In the worst case this backtracking would run O(2^N) complexity, but since `TOP_X` is limited value it should not take too long in real.

I tried to test this code by generating random values and it seems working fine. Full code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/mkamilov/a0341ed921167da438b3030468abaec3)

Comment: I will thoroughly review your answer soon, thanx!

Comment: `TOP_X` is for me to say that I want to generate let's the top `200` set's. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @MosheRabaev right, `TOP_X` means amount of top sets you want to get.

Comment: It's been a while, but your solution is great but for a different problem. In my question I specifically stated that the categories of the set is already predefined, you can only create sets that fit that blueprint. In my example the blueprint that I showed is `Food,Meat,Dairy,Fruit,Vegetable,Grain,Wheat,Barley`.

Comment: And there could be duplicates, it doesn't matter, you could have this set-blueprint for example: `Food,Meat,Food,Fruit,Vegetable,Wheat,Wheat,Barley`

Comment: @MosheRabaev As I remember, my solution does not allow duplicated categories in the output. And that was an idea of the set for me. So you want to allow duplicated categories in the output and you have predefined set of categories that the output set has to match. Did I get you correctly?

Comment: Yes, a predefined set will be given as a blueprint for how all the categories in each newly generated set should look like. It could be unordered it doesn't matter.

Comment: Also just to be clear, duplicate items aren't allowed however duplicate categories can happen if that's how the blueprint set is defined as.

Comment: @MosheRabaev I think you can still use my solution with minor changes. Please refer to the original gist where I added some comments regarding how can you support blueprint.

Comment: It's not a minor change I read your code and I worked an example by paper, and simple if statements to check and continue the search if the categories of set's weren't found won't work, I will add a comment on Github to show you by example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "generating in-order sets".

I think any algorithm is going to generate sets, score them, and then try to generate better sets. Given all the constraints, I do not think you can generate the best set efficiently in one pass.

The 0-1 [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) has been shown to be [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), which means there is no known polynomial time (i.e. O(n^k)) solution. That problem is the same as you would have if, in your input, the random number was always equal to the price and there was only 1 category. In other words, your problem is at least as hard as the knapsack problem, so you cannot expect to find a guaranteed polynomial time solution.

You can generate all valid sets combinatorially pretty easily using nested loops: loop per category, looping over the items in that category. Early on you can improve the efficiency by skipping over an item if it has already been chosen and by skipping over the whole set once you find it is over the price cap. Put those results in a heap and then you can spit them out in order.

If your issue is that you want something with better performance than that, it seems to me more like a [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming), or, more specifically, a [constraint satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) problem. I suggest you look at the techniques used to handle those kinds of problems.